Internet connection not working after reboot/suspend
I have Ubuntu 22.04 and after I reboot or suspend my laptop my wi-fi connects but without internet. This happens not every time, but very often. Other devices do not have this problem.
I've foud out that Internet connects when I restart my Asus router or restart just wireless network on router.
I've tried many solutions from other posts but nothing worked for me.
Please specify which debug information I should provide.
Thank you in advance.

If restarting the router fixes the issue I would suspect a router issue.

This is new router ASUS rt-ax58u, and everything worked fine with the old router (also asus). Maybe there is some specific setting shoud be set, but I tried anything I know.
